# Locals window empty (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I was working on a project just like usual. I run it and check my Locals window only to see it empty. I tried restarting VS and then my computer but it was without success. I tried opening another project and it didn't have that issue. I googled and came across many threads with similar issues. Most of them were VS 2008 or 2010 however.

I reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 only to find that all projects (that I checked (7)) have the same issue. I emptied the symbol cache, changed debugging and other settings as was suggested in some of the answers in other threads but all attempts have failed.

My Locals window:

[image]

General debugging settings:

[image]

If there's anything else I can grab a screenshot of that would help I'll gladly do so.

Comment: You are running the Debug build and not the Release build?

Comment: Yes, I have it set to Debug and x86. The only other options for Debug is Release and Configuration Manager and other option instead of x86 is Configuration Manager.

Comment: @Quaz, (1)whether the debugger breakpoint was really hit?(2) Please make sure that no compiled error during you clean and build your solution.(3) Add the variable to the Watch or view the Autos window, how about the result?

Comment: @JackZhai (1) It seems to work when I put breakpoints in the code, but I didn't have to do that before and I got all local variables, thanks. I can use this if I don't get this sorted out. (2) There are no errors, I rebuilt, just built. Restarted and tried again, no issue there. (3) I added some variables to the Watch and they are just greyed out.

Comment: @JackZhai Could this error have something to do with the issue? : Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game\v4.0_4.0.0.0__842cf8be1de50553\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.This is in my Output window next to the Locals. The same "Cannot find or open the PDB file" is for Xna.Framework.Graphics, Xna.Framework and Xna.Framework.Input.Touch Edit: However the same missing Locals error occurs in projects that are Console or Forms applications

Comment: I always use the debug local window with a breakpoint, you could disable the one you added, and view the breakpoint windows, and check that whether you have added one before which was not hit, for the pdb file issue, you could view the Modules window and load the symbols manually, please also enable the Symbols server under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols, generally this error would generate this issue "breakpoint was not hit".

Comment: @Quaz, what about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view variable in the local window, add a breakpoint in your project, you could view it after the breakpoint is hit.

For the issue "Cannot find or open the PDB file", please enabled "microsoft symbol servers" under the TOOLS-> Options-> Debugging-> Symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Try typing:

> .natvisreload

followed by the Enter key within the Debugger Immediate Window.

Comment: Okay, Could you explain what this command is supposed to do?